# Parse sql select statement to fetch the where clause conditions in python

Tags: python, mysql, parsing, dictionary, sql-parser

I have a sql query and I want to fetch all the conditions in `where` clause into a Python dictionary.

e.g.,

```
import sqlparse

s = "select count(*) from users where employee_type = 'Employee' AND (employment_status = 'Active' OR employment_status = 'On Leave') AND (time_type='Full time' OR country_code <> 'US') AND hire_date < NOW() AND email_work IS NOT NULL AND LENGTH(email_work) > 0 AND NOT (job_profile_id IN ('8802 - Comm Ops - 1', '8801 - CityOps - 2', '10034', '10455', '21014', '21015', '21016', '21018', '21017', '21019') AND country_code = 'IE') AND job_profile_id NOT IN ('20992', '20993', '20994', '20995', '20996', '20997') AND country_code NOT IN ('CN', 'MO', 'SG', 'MY', 'TH', 'VN', 'MM', 'KH', 'PH', 'ID')"

parsed = sqlparse.parse(s)
where = parsed[0][-1]

sql_tokens = []
def get_tokens(where):
    for i in where.tokens:
        try:
            name = i.get_real_name()
            if name and not isinstance(i, sqlparse.sql.Parenthesis):
                # sql_tokens.append("{0} - {1} - {2}".format(str(i), str(name), i.value))
                sql_tokens.append({
                    'key': str(name),
                    'value': i.value,
                })
            else:
                get_tokens(i)
        except Exception as e:
            pass


get_tokens(where)
for i in sql_tokens:
    print i
```

Following is the output

```
{'value': u"employee_type = 'Employee'", 'key': 'employee_type'}
{'value': u"employment_status = 'Active'", 'key': 'employment_status'}
{'value': u"employment_status = 'On Leave'", 'key': 'employment_status'}
{'value': u"time_type='Full time'", 'key': 'time_type'}
{'value': u"country_code <> 'US'", 'key': 'country_code'}
{'value': u'hire_date < NOW()', 'key': 'hire_date'}
{'value': u'email_work', 'key': 'email_work'}
{'value': u'LENGTH(email_work) > 0', 'key': 'LENGTH'}
{'value': u'job_profile_id', 'key': 'job_profile_id'}
{'value': u"country_code = 'IE'", 'key': 'country_code'}
{'value': u'job_profile_id', 'key': 'job_profile_id'}
{'value': u'country_code', 'key': 'country_code'}
```

The problem here is with the `IN` operator.
Check `job_profile_id`, it doesn't contain the list.

On debugging, it doesn't show the list.

I am unable to resolve this issue.

Please help.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the tree structure is different for IN keywords and comparisons. For example, a comparison includes the entire expression underneath it in the tree.

If you use `parsed[0]._pprint_tree()` you can see everything nested under a Comparison node:

```
   |- 2 Comparison 'employ...'
   |  |- 0 Identifier 'employ...'
   |  |  `- 0 Name 'employ...'
   |  |- 1 Whitespace ' '
   |  |- 2 Comparison '='
   |  |- 3 Whitespace ' '
   |  `- 4 Single ''Emplo...'
```

However, the `NOT IN` clause is a series of sequential nodes:

```
   |- 36 Identifier 'job_pr...'
   |  `- 0 Name 'job_pr...'
   |- 37 Whitespace ' '
   |- 38 Keyword 'NOT'
   |- 39 Whitespace ' '
   |- 40 Keyword 'IN'
   |- 41 Whitespace ' '
   |- 42 Parenthesis '('2099...'
   |  |- 0 Punctuation '('
   |  |- 1 IdentifierList ''20992...'
   |  |  |- 0 Single "'20992'"
   |  |  |- 1 Punctuation ','
   |  |  |- 2 Whitespace ' '
   |  |  |- 3 Single "'20993'"
   |  |  |- 4 Punctuation ','
   |  |  |- 5 Whitespace ' '
   |  |  |- 6 Single "'20994'"
   |  |  |- 7 Punctuation ','
   |  |  |- 8 Whitespace ' '
   |  |  |- 9 Single "'20995'"
   |  |  |- 10 Punctuation ','
   |  |  |- 11 Whitespace ' '
   |  |  |- 12 Single "'20996'"
   |  |  |- 13 Punctuation ','
   |  |  |- 14 Whitespace ' '
   |  |  `- 15 Single "'20997'"
   |  `- 2 Punctuation ')'
```

Your best bet is to watch for identifiers, then jump ahead and save the value of the next parenthesis node. While this doesn't handle every possible situation, it does handle your SQL statement and returns the value of `job_profile_id`.

Here's my modified code:

```
import sqlparse

s = "select count(*) from users where employee_type = 'Employee' AND (employment_status = 'Active' OR employment_status = 'On Leave') AND (time_type='Full time' OR country_code <> 'US') AND hire_date < NOW() AND email_work IS NOT NULL AND LENGTH(email_work) > 0 AND NOT (job_profile_id IN ('8802 - Comm Ops - 1', '8801 - CityOps - 2', '10034', '10455', '21014', '21015', '21016', '21018', '21017', '21019') AND country_code = 'IE') AND job_profile_id NOT IN ('20992', '20993', '20994', '20995', '20996', '20997') AND country_code NOT IN ('CN', 'MO', 'SG', 'MY', 'TH', 'VN', 'MM', 'KH', 'PH', 'ID')"

parsed = sqlparse.parse(s)
where = parsed[0][-1]

sql_tokens = []
def get_tokens(where):
    identifier = None
    for i in where.tokens:
        try:
            name = i.get_real_name()
            if name and isinstance(i, sqlparse.sql.Identifier):
                identifier = i
            elif identifier and isinstance(i, sqlparse.sql.Parenthesis):
                sql_tokens.append({
                    'key': str(identifier),
                    'value': token.value
                })
            elif name:
                identifier = None
                # sql_tokens.append("{0} - {1} - {2}".format(str(i), str(name), i.value))
                sql_tokens.append({
                    'key': str(name),
                    'value': u''.join(token.value for token in i.flatten()),
                })
            else:
                get_tokens(i)
        except Exception as e:
            pass

get_tokens(where)
print sql_tokens
```

Comment: Awesome! Works!